# Unable to get the initial date of the month using withDayOfMonth

Tags: java, arraylist, java-stream, java-time

I want to get the first datetime of the month for the given date-time as follows: For the date `19-04-2018 19:00:00` (dd-MM-yyyy HH:mm:ss) it should be `01-04-2018 00:00:00`.

I have tried the below code, but it gives the empty list.

`startDate` may contains the value like `01-04-2018 00:00:00`.

```
List<scPosR> scPosRListPerStoreAndTimeStamp =  spst.stream().filter(
                scPosR -> Timestamp.valueOf(scPosR.getTransactionDate()
                        .toLocalDateTime()
                        .toLocalDate()
                        .withDayOfMonth(1)
                        .atStartOfDay())
                .equals(startDate))
        .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Can anyone please suggest me to do it?

Comment: are you sure that your list contains at list one object with matching  `startDate` value? for me `localDate.withDayOfMonth(1).atStartOfDay()` returns expected value

Comment: What is the type of `startDate`? If it is anything other than `Timestamp`, `equals` will return false.

Answer (score 1):

I cannot tell what went wrong. Like Pavan observed, your code works as expected also on my computer and returns a list containing the objects with a transaction date in April. One possible explanation is if your `startDate` variable doesn’t hold a `Timestamp`, but some other (runtime) type. Another possible explanation is a timezone issue: if your `startDate` timestamp was created in a different time zone, it won’t be equal to the timestamps created in your stream filter.

Anyway here’s a simpler version of your code hoping it will also be simpler to debug.

```
    YearMonth month = YearMonth.of(2018, Month.APRIL);

    List<ScPosR> scPosRListPerStoreAndTimeStamp =  spst.stream()
            .filter(scPosR -> YearMonth.from(scPosR.getTransactionDate().toLocalDateTime())
                    .equals(month))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Still better if you could get completely rid of the outdated `Timestamp` class, of course.